# The Requested URL Was not found on this server. Problem with cpanel while hosting React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

Hy fellow Developers,

I have added homepage to my package.json

I did make a build then zipped it and then uploaded it in public_html folder in cpanel
then unzipped it, and removed all the files other than the files of build folder, my public_html [image: screenshot of folder]folder, looks like this

As i go to my website i.e strea.com everything woks fine, but as soon as i try to go on any other links like /contact it gives errors

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Please help me rectify this situation.

If you need any additional information please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that is to change your routing method from **BrowserRouter** to **HashRouter**.

Let me know if you encounter any other issue.

Comment: not a good answer, your answer suggests that REACT SHOULD REMOVE BrowserRouter altogether